# I get java.lang.NullPointerException while using driver.get

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate search functionality on a website. While running the test case, `Firefox` browser is opened and the website is rendered correctly but still system shows null pointer on line where i call `driver.get(URL);` The code snippet is as follows:

```
    package testcases;


    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class SaavnSearchWeb {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://saavn.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
      public void testSaavnSearchWeb() throws Exception {

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/s/artist/deepika-padukone-album/36LfdYhYGvc_");
        if (isElementPresent(By.id("q"))){
            driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys("cocktail");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tum Hi Ho Bandhu")).click();
        }
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }

      private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

The stack trace is as follow:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at testcases.SaavnSearchWeb.testSaavnSearchWeb(SaavnSearchWeb.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: post the class completely if possible .. want to know how driver is declared

Comment: `public class SaavnSearchWeb {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  'before'
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
    baseUrl = "http://www.saavn.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

 'test'
  public void testSaavnSearchWeb() throws Exception {
   
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/s/artist/deepika-padukone-album/36LfdYhYGvc_");
    if (isElementPresent(By.id("q"))){
     driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys("cocktail");
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tum Hi Ho Bandhu")).click();
      }
  }`

Comment: tried your code.. No error for me. The test case passed successfully. Which version of Selenium and JUnit are you using. Also, you are running this as JUnit, right?

Comment: Agreed. Code works fine. Not sure if `By.id("q")` is a valid locator here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Junit: 4.12
selenium: 2.47

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right protocol for the url. Change the baseUrl to as follows:

```
baseUrl = "http://saavn.com";
```

And run the code.

Comment: @A Gill- tried with this but same error. When i run the testcse, url is invoked correctly once but control does not go to the next line and after some time. i get null pointer exception again at the same line for driver.get(URL), but the invoked browser is still open

Comment: Try this.`public class SaavnSearchWeb {
 private WebDriver driver; 
 private String baseUrl;

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception { 
 driver = new FirefoxDriver (); 
 baseUrl = "http://www.saavn.com"; 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
 } 

 @Test
 public void testSaavnSearchWeb() throws Exception { 
     driver.get(baseUrl + "/s/artist/deepika-padukone-album/36LfdYhYGvc_");
 }`

Comment: @A Gill: control does not move ahead to the next line in after this line of my code

Comment: Can you please post your full code and the error stack to the original question. I am sure someone will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: So you are saying, the `driver.findElement();` line is not getting executed but the you are able to go the defined url?

Comment: @A Gill: thats the isssue I am facing

Comment: Ok, so thats a different question now. You original question says you are getting java.lang.NullPointerException while you are trying to execute `driver.get()` but that problem seems to be resolved. Please update the question with what you want to accomplish (whats the use case) or please ask a new one.